# Grouped aggregate counts for each date in a series of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get grouped `task` counts by `state` over a **series** of dates using the following tables:

```
tasks
-----
| id | title       | state_id | inserted_at         |
| -- | ----------- | -------- | ------------------- |
| 1  | First Task  | 1        | 2022-05-05 19:16:44 |
| 2  | Second Task | 1        | 2022-05-07 18:54:40 |
| 3  | Third Task  | 1        | 2022-05-07 19:18:28 |
| 4  | Fourth Task | 1        | 2022-05-10 15:28:57 |
```

```
task_states
-----
| id | label      |
| -- | ---------- |
| 1  | Assigns    |
| 2  | In Process |
| 3  | Completed  |
```

```
task_logs
-----
| id | event   | target | value      | task_id | inserted_at        |
| -- | ------- | ------ | ---------- | ------- | -------------------|
| 1  | changed | state  | Assigns    | 1       | 2022-05-05 19:16:44|
| 2  | changed | state  | In Progress| 1       | 2022-05-06 11:43:14|
| 3  | changed | state  | Assigns    | 2       | 2022-05-07 18:54:40|
| 4  | changed | state  | Assigns    | 3       | 2022-05-07 19:18:28|
| 5  | changed | state  | Completed  | 1       | 2022-05-08 12:11:38|
| 6  | changed | state  | In Progress| 2       | 2022-05-09 09:22:53|
| 7  | changed | state  | Assigns    | 4       | 2022-05-10 15:28:57|
| 8  | changed | state  | Completed  | 2       | 2022-05-11 11:21:53|
| 9  | changed | state  | In Progress| 3       | 2022-05-11 17:42:02|
```

There isn't a consistent daily "state" record for each task because `task_logs` only has entries for when a task changes state. This means I have to get the last "state change" log for each task prior to a specified date. I've got the following query working to get the task count in each state for one day ago:

```
SELECT date('2022-05-10'), state.id as state_id, state.label, count(sub.id)
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.id) t.id, logs.value
   FROM tasks t
   INNER JOIN task_logs logs ON logs.task_id = t.id
   WHERE date(logs.inserted_at) <= date('2022-05-10') AND logs.target = 'state'
   ORDER BY t.id, logs.inserted_at DESC
) sub
RIGHT JOIN task_states state ON state.label = sub.value
GROUP BY state.id
ORDER BY state.id;
------------------
| date       | state_id | label      | count |
| ---------- | -------- | ---------- | ----- |
| 2022-05-10 | 1        | Assigns    | 2     |
| 2022-05-10 | 2        | In Process | 1     |
| 2022-05-10 | 3        | Completed  | 1     |
```

My trouble comes from trying to combine the query above with `generate_series` to get the **daily** count over a series of dates, something like:

```
| date       | state_id | label       | count |
| ---------- | -------- | ----------- | ----- |
| 2022-05-05 | 1        | Assigns     | 1     |
| 2022-05-05 | 2        | In Progress | 0     |
| 2022-05-05 | 3        | Complete    | 0     |
| 2022-05-06 | 1        | Assigns     | 0     |
| 2022-05-06 | 2        | In Progress | 1     |
| 2022-05-06 | 3        | Complete    | 0     |
| 2022-05-07 | 1        | Assigns     | 2     |
| 2022-05-07 | 2        | In Progress | 1     |
| 2022-05-07 | 3        | Complete    | 0     |
| 2022-05-08 | 1        | Assigns     | 2     |
| 2022-05-08 | 2        | In Progress | 0     |
| 2022-05-08 | 3        | Complete    | 1     |
| 2022-05-09 | 1        | Assigns     | 1     |
| 2022-05-09 | 2        | In Progress | 1     |
| 2022-05-09 | 3        | Complete    | 1     |
| 2022-05-10 | 1        | Assigns     | 2     |
| 2022-05-10 | 2        | In Progress | 1     |
| 2022-05-10 | 3        | Complete    | 1     |
| 2022-05-11 | 1        | Assigns     | 1     |
| 2022-05-11 | 2        | In Progress | 1     |
| 2022-05-11 | 3        | Complete    | 2     |
```

Here's a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dc126172733b5e3700069c52eb0f3eaf) setup with the tables above. Any thoughts/ideas on how to perform the query above (or rewrite it) for each date in a series of dates (`generate_series(current_date - interval '5 day', current_date, '1 day')`) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a stored function to loop through the generated series of dates and capture each daily aggregated snapshot:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_daily_log_agg(_interval_days TEXT)
  RETURNS TABLE ("date" TEXT,
                 state_id INTEGER, 
                 state_label TEXT,
                 "count" INTEGER)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$

DECLARE dt RECORD;
BEGIN 

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE daily_log_agg (
        "date" TEXT, 
        state_id INTEGER, 
        state_label TEXT, 
        "count" INTEGER
    );
    

    FOR dt IN SELECT dates FROM generate_series( 
            current_date - _interval_days::interval,
            current_date, '1 day' 
        ) AS dates LOOP
        
        INSERT INTO daily_log_agg ("date", state_id, state_label, "count")
        SELECT dt.dates AS "date",
               state.id AS state_id, 
               state.label, 
               COUNT(sub.id) AS "count"
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.id) t.id, logs.value
            FROM tasks t
            INNER JOIN task_logs logs ON logs.task_id = t.id
            WHERE date(logs.inserted_at) <= dt.dates
              AND logs.target = 'state'
            ORDER BY t.id, logs.inserted_at DESC
        ) sub
        RIGHT JOIN task_states state ON state.label = sub.value
        GROUP BY state.id
        ORDER BY state.id;
        
   END LOOP; 
   
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * FROM daily_log_agg;
END
$func$;


SELECT * FROM build_daily_log_agg('12 days');
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=83ff955a01c27ddffe07868989d50337)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for trying to help me out! I've tried a similar query to that in the past, but unfortunately, that gives me the count of `tasks` moved to a "state" **on** that date, but doesn't count tasks whose "state" wasn't changed that day. That's why the `WHERE date(logs.inserted_at) <= current_date - interval '1 day'` clause was used in my sample, so the most recent log (not only ones on a date) were counted.

Comment: Your post data of one row does not match desired results. Do you need to fill forward or backward? Where do counts derive? Can you set up a Postgres [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with [mcve]?

Comment: sorry if the data I initially provided wasn't clear! Here's a Postgres [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=db4eb5076afe24101eeac0953df277b4) with a better explanation of the data and desired result

Comment: See edit with online fiddle demo, now using a window function to sum counts across days. Results do not match your daily examples due to `DISTINCT ON`. Need to handle later.

Comment: could you be more specific with what you mean by handling `DISTINCT ON` later to get the results to match the examples? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I tried many ways even recursive CTEs. Short of too complex and unmaintainable a solution, consider using a programming language (Python, Java, PHP, R) connected to DB or even Postgres' procedural, pl/pgsql  to iterate through range of dates and pass parameter into `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses. `DISTINCT ON` taking latest row per id requires a snapshot of data on each date. Tough to do in just set-based SQL.

Comment: that's what I feared. Currently, I'm iterating through a date range in the language connected to our app's DB (Elixir). I hoped to get everything into SQL to limit the number of DB calls (especially for large ranges). This is probably a symptom of trying to brute force this into an older DB structure created before we wanted to track these metrics. I'll update the question with the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=db4eb5076afe24101eeac0953df277b4) data in case anyone else has ideas, but I'll probably have to make some DB tweaks. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I revamped my answer for a stored function using plpgsql. See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=83ff955a01c27ddffe07868989d50337)

Comment: that's really cool, and thanks for all the help! I think I'm going to stick with iterating through a date range in Elixir and passing that into `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses. It's great to know it can be done with a stored function using plpgsql, but any performance boost that provides most likely doesn't outweigh the increased complexity that comes with it. Down the road, I'll start taking daily snapshots of key metrics to simplify this whole issue!